# Change CSS with javascript using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I do not know how to access a specific CSS using javascript.

Let us say,

```
#menu { color: red; }
```

can be accessed by

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.color = "blue";
```

But I want to access

```
#menu li a { height: 10%; }
```

How do I access that using document.getElementById() ?

Comment: Is jQuery an option? If yes: `$('#menu li a').css('height', '10%');` Otherwise the necessary DOM traversal is much more complicated unless you only want to support modern browsers which have the `querySelectorAll` method.

Comment: Do you want it to affect any future elements? Or just those that exist at the time where your code runs?

Comment: @ThiefMaster only when the code runs. I could use Jquery, so things are very simple. thanks!

Comment: @LINGS: If you don't have much JavaScript on your page, there's a very good chance that loading jQuery will be overkill. The jQuery zealots rarely mention that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Plain JavaScript solution:

You cannot use `getElementById()` in this case since its purpose is only to query id attributes, but you can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) in context of `#menu`:

```
var m = document.getElementById('menu');
// Get all <li> children of #menu
var lis = m.getElementsByTagName('li');
// Loop over them
for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
  // Get all <a> children of each <li>
  var atags = lis[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var a = 0; a<atags.length; a++) {
    // And set their color in a loop.
    atags[a].style.color = 'blue';
    // or change some other property
    atags[a].style.height = '25%'; 
  }
}
```

#### jQuery Solution:

If you are able to use jQuery, this becomes exceedingly simpler:

```
$('#menu li a').css('color', 'blue');
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't; you'd have to find all the `<a>` tags that matched that criteria.

The `.getElementById()` function is about getting an element by a unique "id" string.  If you need to get elements otherwise, there are other APIs to use: `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByClass()`, `.querySelectorAll()`, etc.  Browser support varies, and even `.getElementById()` is different between IE and other browsers.